# Determining the starting position of an iterator

Tags: c++, const-iterator

Consider a C++ vector container of objects, with fields a and time.  We want to find the first item in the container that occurs after the current time (let's call it item N) , and then iterate over the container starting at the first item that occurs at an earlier time with field a having a certain value  (so basically, from [N-1, inf)).   Assuming the property is not found,  we would perform the second iteration over the entire list.

Would the following code work?  (in the example, we want to find the most recent item with a >= 5 ).
Is there a better way to do this?

```
myVectorType::const_iterator cBegin = myVectorObj.begin();
myVectorType::const_iterator cEnd = myVectorObj.end();

// Find the most recent item with a >= 5
for (myVectorObj::const_iterator iter = cBegin;  iter != cEnd; ++iter)
{
  if ((*iter).time >= currentTime)
  {
    // Found an item that is in the future -  we should have determined the location of the most
    // recent item with the propery we're looking for.
    break;
  }
  else if ((*iter).a >= 5)
  {
    // Past item with a >= 5.  Save the location.
    cBegin = iter; 
  }
}

// Iterate over the container, beginning at the most recent item with a >= 5, if it was found.
for (;  cBegin != cEnd; ++cBegin)
{
  dostuff();
}
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a school assignment (especially the part where you ask "would the following code work?" - this indicates you haven't tried to compile or debug this code)

Comment: If the vector is sorted by time, have a look at std::lower_bound

Answer (score 0):

Two step process. First, find the field after current time:

```
auto afterCurrent = std::find_if(myVectorObj.begin(), myVectorObj.end(), [=](const Field& field){
    return field.time >= currentTime;
});
```

Then, find the element BEFORE `afterCurrent` with a >= 5

```
auto reverse = myVectorType::const_reverse_iterator(afterCurrent);

auto atLeast5_rev = std::find_if(reverse, myVectorType.rend(), [=](const Field& field) {
    return field.a >= 5;
});

// convert back to forward iterator
auto atLeast5 = --(atLeast5_rev.base());
```

Then iterate from `atLeast5` to the end.